# Losing characters when converting between hex and ascii

Tags: java, hex, ascii

```
import java.lang.*;

public class asciiHex{
    public static void main(String args[]){
        String ascii1 = "e v e r y s e c o n d c h a r";
        String hex = "";
        String ascii2 = "";
        char[] chars = ascii1.toCharArray();

        for(int i = 0; i < ascii1.length(); i++){
            hex += (Integer.toHexString( (int)chars[i]));
        }

        System.out.println(ascii1);
        System.out.println(hex);

        for(int i = 0; i < hex.length(); i+=2){
            String temp = hex.substring(i, i+=2);
            ascii2 += ((char)Integer.parseInt(temp, 16));
        }

        System.out.println(ascii2);
    }
}
```

This is my code. It's supposed to take a string and convert it from ascii to hex, then back. When I run the program, it somehow loses every second character. I'm pretty sure it's a problem with the way I'm using the substrings, but I don't understand why it's behaving this way.

Thanks.

Comment: You don't need to do `import java.lang.*`. Everything in `java.lang` is imported by default

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're incrementing your counter (`i`) twice, that's why it skips every second character:

```
for(int i = 0; i < hex.length(); i+=2){     // <-- first increment
    String temp = hex.substring(i, i+=2);   // <-- second increment
    ascii2 += ((char)Integer.parseInt(temp, 16));
}
```

Should be:

```
for(int i = 0; i < hex.length(); i+=2) {    // <-- increment here
    String temp = hex.substring(i, i+2);    // <-- do not increment here
    ascii2 += ((char)Integer.parseInt(temp, 16));
}
```

Comment: Awesome, thanks. Is this like the difference between i++ and i+1?

Answer (score 2):

You have 2 instances where you have done `i+=2`.
In for loop `for(int i = 0; i < hex.length(); i+=2)`, and also in substring `String temp = hex.substring(i, i+=2);`.
Make `String temp = hex.substring(i, i+2);` to make it work as expected.